# Make a Tv simulator - Python

Tags: python, pickle

I am really new to Python and I have to make a tv simulator. I have searched basically the entire net but I cant really find my answer. My problem is that we have to save the state of the tv in a file and when we reopen the programm it must retrieve its previous state i.e. channel, show, volume. I use pickle for saving the file, but it does not retrieve the previous state.

Hopefully I have been adequatly specific otherwise feel free to ask me for clarification.

Thank you in advance

```
class Television(object):
    currentState = []

    def __init__(self,volume,channel,show):
        self.volume=volume
        self.channel=channel
        self.show=show

    def changeChannel(self,choice):

        self.channel=choice 
        return self.channel

    def increaseVolume(self,volume):
        if volume in range(0,9):
            self.volume+=1
        return self.volume

    def decreaseVolume(self,volume):
        if volume in range(1,10):            
            self.volume-=1        
        return self.volume

    #def __str__(self):
        #return "[channel: %s show: %s,volume: %s]" % (self.channel, self.show, self.volume)
    def __str__(self):
        return  "Channel: "+str(self.channel)+\
                "\nShow: "+ str(self.show)+\
                "\nVolume: "+ str(self.volume)
                                #printing object, state = "print(object)"
    def getState(self):         
        return self.volume

    def setState (self,channel,show):
        self.volume=5
        self.channel=channel[1]
        self.show=show[1]


#####################################################################

from tvsimulator import* 

import pickle, os.path

#from builtins import int

channel = ["1. Mtv","2. Tv 3","2. Svt","4. Kanal4"]

show = ["Music is life", "Har du tur i karlek?", "Pengar ar inte allt","Vem vill inte bli miljonar"]

volume = 5

global myTv

livingRoomTv = Television(channel,show,volume)

kitchenTv = Television(channel,show,volume)  




def saveFile(): 

    with open("tvState.pkl",'wb') as outfile:

        pickle.dump(livingRoomTv,outfile)
        pickle.dump(kitchenTv,outfile)

def importFile():       

    with open("tvState.pkl",'rb') as infile:

        livingRoomTv = pickle.load(infile)
        kitchenTv = pickle.load(infile)


def channelMenu(myTv):    
    for i in channel:
        print(i)                
    choice =int(input(print("Which channel do you want?")))
    choice = channel[choice-1]                    
    myTv.changeChannel(choice)
    selection =myTv.changeChannel(choice) 
    return selection   


def methodSelection(myTv):  

    print("1: Change channel")
    print("2: Volume Up")
    print("3: Volume Down")
    print("4: Return to main menu")       
    choice = int(input(print("\nPleas make a selection from the above list\n")))   
    print(myTv)
    try:                    
        if choice ==1:   
            channelMenu(myTv)
            print(myTv)          
            methodSelection(myTv)
        if choice ==2:
            myTv.increaseVolume(volume)
            print(myTv)
            methodSelection(myTv)
        if choice ==3:
            myTv.decreaseVolume(volume)
            print(myTv)
            methodSelection(myTv)
        if choice ==4:
            mainMenu()
    except:
        print("Wrong selection, please try again")




def mainMenu(): 

    print("1: Livingroom Tv")
    print("2: Kitchen TV")
    print("3: Exit\n")    
    choice = int(input(print("Please make a selection from the above list")))          
    try:              
        if choice == 1:
            print("Living room\n")       
            print(livingRoomTv)
            myTv = livingRoomTv        
            methodSelection(myTv)       
        if choice == 2:
            print("Kitchen\n")      
            print(kitchenTv)
            myTv=kitchenTv        
            methodSelection(myTv)        
        if choice == 3:
            saveFile()
            print("Tv Shut Down")
            exit
    except:
        print("Wrong selection, please try again")



def startUp():

    if os.path.isfile("tvState.pkl"):
        print("Tv restored to previous state")
        importFile()
        kitchenTv.getState()
        livingRoomTv.getState()
        mainMenu()               

    else:
        print("Welcome")
        kitchenTv.setState(channel, show)
        livingRoomTv.setState(channel, show)
        saveFile()
        mainMenu()    

startUp()
```

Comment: The way to solve any problem is to reduce it until you are left with the _core_ of the problem only. In this case; remove stuff from your program until you are left with only the thing you can't get to work. Maybe that would be a program that reads the state from a file and prints it? Then you fix that problem, and put back all the other stuff.

Comment: Pleas post a [mcve]. I do not think you need that wall of code to show your issue with pickle.

Comment: "_I have searched basically the entire net_" You must have been doing this for quite some time now.

Comment: @MagnusHoff Thank you for your suggestion. I will try it next time.

Comment: @Goyo The problem is resolved now, but I will keep it for future reference. It is just i am new to coding so i dont know exactly what would have effected the program.

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey Some days indeed

Answer (score 1):

Using global variables for reading is no problem, thus explaining that the `save` feature works, but assignments to globals are not automatic: You have to make your variables global or it will create local variables instead that will be lost as soon as they go out of scope (thus explaining why your state is not reloaded).

The global variables can be reached by adding `global v` where `v` is the variable to be seen as global in the function:

```
def importFile():       
    global livingRoomTv # link to the global variable
    global kitchenTv    # link to the global variable

    with open("tvState.pkl",'rb') as infile:

        livingRoomTv = pickle.load(infile)
        kitchenTv = pickle.load(infile)
```

Simple MCVE:

```
z=[1,2,3]

def load():
    #global z
    z=set()

load()

print(z)
```

prints `[1,2,3]`

Now uncommenting `global z`, it prints `set([])`, meaning I was successfully able to change `z` in the function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. You solved my problem.. I really appreciate that you went through the whole "wall" of code, i understand it is messy, so next time i have a qustion I will try to minimize the code.

Comment: I did not went through the "wall". I just checked both load/save routines and understood that it was about globals (which is a real trap, so I often use singleton classes so I can manipulate only member variables, no globals). Note my [mcve] which is 5 lines long.